# If we got a non-singular matrix $A$, how is the operation $Ã = (A^T)^{-1}$ called? And why is a matrix $A$ orthogonal if $A = Ã$?

Tags: matrices, transpose

This was just introduced in our Differential Geometry course, but no name was given to this.

In the end, it's just the inverse transpose matrix, but does it have its "own" name?

Also, I don't quite understand the reason why a matrix A is orthogonal if $A = Ã$

I mean, as far as I know, a matrix A is orthogonal if it's columns (or rows) are orthogonal to each other. But why is this (apparently) equal to the condition, that $A = Ã$?

Comment: Have you tried to calculate $A^TA$ (and $AA^T$) for an orthogonal matrix? What happens?

Comment: I tried it for $A = \begin{pmatrix}1&1&3\\ 1&0&1\\ 0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$ right now which should be an orthogonal matrix, but I don't get anything special

Comment: Actually, a matrix is orthogonal if its columns and rows are **orthonormal**, not orthogonal, although the nomenclature implies otherwise. So the example you've taken here isn't an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: The columns of that matrix aren't orthogonal (they have dot products 1 and 4, not 0). And an orthogonal matrix is also required to have unit-length columns.